# Blank PDF Generated on Use of getContentAsPDF on A VF Page When Called From an LWC Component on a Community Site

Tags: callout, community-builder, guest-user, getcontentaspdf

As the title says I'm calling getContentAsPDF for a VF page from an LWC component which is used on a community site. It works for Authenticated users but for Guest Users returns a blank PDF. I've done everything I've seen in similar questions such as adding the VF pages and APEX classes to the guest user profile along with the necessary object permissions, annotations with "@future(callout=true)" and all classes involved are run as "without sharing" besides so I really can't figure out what the issue is.

Code:

```
  @AuraEnabled
  public static void generateDocuments(String token) {
    try {
      VFtoPDF(token);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  @future(callout=true)
  public static void VFtoPDF(String token) {
    try {
      Object obj = [
        SELECT token, obj_name
        FROM Object
        WHERE token = :token
      ];
      
      List<Attachment> documents = new List<Attachment>();

      for (Integer i = 0; i < no_of_documents; i++) {
        PageReference pdf = new PageReference('/apex/' + visforce_page_name);
        pdf.getParameters().put('token', obj.token);

        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        attach.Body = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
        attach.Name = attachment_name;
        attach.IsPrivate = false;
        attach.ParentId = obj.Id;
        documents.add(attach);
      }
      upsert documents Name;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've gotten around this is with Platform Events.

Create a Platform Event that the Guest user has access to create. Then, create a trigger (after insert) on the Platform Event, and from there execute the logic to save the VF as PDF. Just make sure the Automated Process user has access to the visualforce page and any apex controller.

Comment: I'm trying that but it seems the Trigger never fires in the first place for some reason.

Comment: Ah the Automated Process has no access to a necessary class is the issue. But I've given it to the Automated Process user and the error is still the same.

Comment: Solved it. Just had to find the Automated Process profile through SOQL and give it all the necessary permissions. ```SELECT ProfileId FROM User WHERE alias = 'autoproc'``` and take the Id that and put at the end of the profile edit link. ```/_ui/system/user/ProfileApexClassPermissionEdit/e?profile_id=```.

Comment: Interesting. I usually just create a permission set and assign it to the automated process user.

Comment: Didn't work for some reason. I gave the Automated Process user's profile the permissions and it still failed so I ended up doing it that way.